# Perl Module using %EXPORT_TAGS

Tags: perl, module

I'm having trouble properly using %EXPORT_TAGS in my Perl module.  In **Solver.pl** I have:

```
use MatrixFunctions qw(:Normal);
```

Then inside **MatrixFunctions.pm**, I have:

```
package MatrixFunctions;

use strict;
use Exporter;
use vars qw($VERSION @ISA @EXPORT @EXPORT_OK %EXPORT_TAGS);

$VERSION     = 1.00;
@ISA         = qw(Exporter);
@EXPORT      = ();
@EXPORT_OK   = qw(&det &identityMatrix &matrixAdd 
    &matrixScalarMultiply &matrixMultiplication);
%EXPORT_TAGS = ( Det => [qw(&det)],
    Normal => [qw(&det &identityMatrix &matrixAdd 
        &matrixScalarMultiply &matrixMultiplication)]);
```

However it only works when I have @EXPORT_OK including all the methods.  If I have

```
@EXPORT_OK   = ();
```

I have the error:

```
"matrixScalarMultiply" is not exported by the MatrixFunctions module
 "det" is not exported by the MatrixFunctions module
 "matrixAdd" is not exported by the MatrixFunctions module
 "matrixMultiplication" is not exported by the MatrixFunctions module
 "identityMatrix" is not exported by the MatrixFunctions module
Can't continue after import errors at Solver.pl line 6.
BEGIN failed--compilation aborted at Solver.pl line 6.
```

The point of using `qw(:Normal)` in my **Solver.p**l file is so that I can have @EXPORT_OK empty I thought.  What am I doing wrong?

Comment: The point of using tags is it allows you to group exports allowing you to have `@EXPORT` (not `@EXPORT_OK`) empty and still be easy for your users to export common sets.  Without `@EXPORT_OK` users could could see everything: including the big board!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`perldoc -f Exporter`](http://perldoc.perl.org/Exporter.html#Advanced-Features) under the Advanced Features section:

> e.g., Module.pm defines:
>
> ```
> @EXPORT = qw(A1 A2 A3 A4 A5);
> @EXPORT_OK = qw(B1 B2 B3 B4 B5);
> %EXPORT_TAGS = (T1 => [qw(A1 A2 B1 B2)], T2 => [qw(A1 A2 B3 B4)]);
> ```
>
> Note that you cannot use tags in @EXPORT or @EXPORT_OK.
>
> **Names in EXPORT_TAGS must also appear in @EXPORT or @EXPORT_OK.**

The bolded section above explains that you are *required* to have the functions you wish to place in `%EXPORT_TAGS` in either `@EXPORT_OK` or `@EXPORT`

A pattern that I have started using is to defined everything that I want to allow to be exported in `@EXPORT_OK`, then use `@EXPORT_OK` to build an `:all' tag:

```
our @ISA = qw(Exporter);
our @EXPORT_OK = qw/raspberry apple/;

our %EXPORT_TAGS = (
    'all' => \@EXPORT_OK,
);
```

Answer (score 1):

*[Not an answer, but a follow-up to large for a comment]*

If you want `@EXPORT_OK` automatically populated, you can use the following:

```
push @EXPORTER_OK, map @$_, values %EXPORT_TAGS;
```

Exporter doesn't care about duplicate entries. If you do, you can use the following instead:

```
my %EXPORT_OK;
@EXPORT_OK = grep !$EXPORT_OK{$_}++,
    @EXPORT_OK, map @$_, values %EXPORT_TAGS;
```

So, after some cleaning up, your code would be the following:

```
package MatrixFunctions;

use strict;
use warnings;

use Exporter qw( import );

our $VERSION     = 1.00;
our @EXPORT      = ();
our @EXPORT_OK   = ();
our %EXPORT_TAGS = (
    Det    => [qw( det )],
    Normal => [qw( det identityMatrix matrixAdd matrixScalarMultiply matrixMultiplication )],
);

push @EXPORTER_OK, map @$_, values %EXPORT_TAGS;
```